# How to add adsence verification code to a asp.net website

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net, adsense

I have made a asp.net website and I juste want to get the adsence but everytime I past the verification code in my .aspx file its says Adsense code was not found heres my code(i put the verification code in between the content but stack wont let me write it).Google says to put it in the head.

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

Comment: You have an alertantive way to verify Adsense uploading an HTML file to your server. In this way you haven't to add anything to the head.

Comment: thank you very much but witch html file to download (sorry for the bad grammar i speak french)

Comment: My mistake, seems that Google removed that option, now add the code to head is the unique choice. Remember thay ou have to add the code at the HEAD section.

Comment: Yeah i try in the head of the asp:content but it do not work  thank you if anyone know how to solve hit me up :)